# Evaluating $ \int \frac{ 1 } { \sin x - \cos x - 1} dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry, indefinite-integrals

Below is a problem I attempted. However, I failed to find the right approach.

Problem: Perform the following integration:
$$ \int \dfrac{ 1 } { \sin x - \cos x - 1} dx$$

Answer:

Let $I$ be the integral we are trying to evaluate. My first approach is to
try to simplify the denominator by using the idenity $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$.
\begin{align*}
I &= \int \dfrac{1 } { \sin x - (\cos x + 1)}dx \\
I &= \int \dfrac{ ( \sin x + (\cos x + 1))  }
 { ( \sin x + (\cos x + 1))( \sin x - (\cos x + 1))}dx \\
%
I &= \int \dfrac{ ( \sin x + (\cos x + 1)) }
 {\sin^2x - \sin x(\cos x + 1) + \sin x (\cos x + 1) - (\cos^2 x + 1)^2} dx\\
%
I &= \int \dfrac{ ( \sin x + \cos x + 1)  }
 {\sin^2x - \cos^2x - 2\cos x - 1} dx\\
\end{align*}
At this point, I do not see how to make progress. I was hoping for a
$\sin^2x + \cos^2x$ in the denominator.

My second approach.
\begin{align*}
I &= \int \dfrac{ (\cos x) \,\, dx } { \sin x \cos x - \cos^2x - \cos x } \\
I &= \int \dfrac{ (\cos x) \,\, dx }
 { \sin x \cos x - \cos^2x - (1 - \sin^2 x) - \sqrt{1-\sin^2 x} } \\
\end{align*}
Now I can apply the subsutution $u  = \sin x$ and get rid of the trig functions.
\begin{align*}
I &= \int \dfrac{ du } { u^{\frac{3}{2}} - (1-u^2) - u^{ \frac{1}{2}} } \\
I &= \int \dfrac{ du } { u^2 + u^{\frac{3}{2}} - u^{ \frac{1}{2}} - 1 } 
\end{align*}
Again, I do not see how to make progress.

My third approach is to dividend numerator and denominator by $\cos^2 x$ hoping to setup a substitution like $u =  \tan  x$.
\begin{align*}
I &= \int \dfrac{ (\sec^2 x) \,\, dx }
 { \dfrac{ \tan x}{\cos x} - \sec x - \sec^2 x } \\
\end{align*}
What is the right way to solve this problem?

Note: I was planning on adding the homework tag to this post (despite the fact I am not in school) because I am not looking for the answer. I am looking for guidance to get there. When  I attempted to use that tag, I got a message saying please do not use it. So I did not.

Comment: Looks like Weierstrass substitution would work

Comment: You may be interested in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioche%27s_rules

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the famous Weierstrass substitution, let $t=\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$, the we have:
$$\sin x=\frac{2t}{1+t^2} \hspace{1cm} \cos x=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2} \hspace{1cm} \text{d}x=\frac{2}{1+t^2}\text{d}t$$
now the integral reduces to
$$\int\frac{\frac{2}{1+t^2}}  {\frac{2t}{1+t^2}-\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}-1}dt=$$
$$=\int\frac{1}{t-1}dt$$
and this can is just
$$\log |t - 1| + C$$

Comment: I do not understand how you  find $\sin x$ in terms of $t$ I do not understand how you  find $\cos x$ in terms of $t$. Could you provide some more detail in your answer?

Comment: I see more detail on the web. You do not have to bother.

Comment: Your experssion for $dx$ is wrong. Please edit your answer.

Comment: @TravisWillse fixed, thank you

Comment: The tangent half-angle substitution was used by Euler in 1768 while Weierstrass was born in 1815 !!

Comment: This is even worse than L'Hôpital's story :-@ClaudeLeibovici

Answer (score 8):

Another approach

$$ I=\int \dfrac{ 1 } { \sin x - \cos x - 1}dx = \int \dfrac{ \sin x - \cos x + 1 } { (\sin x - \cos x)^2 - 1} dx=\int \dfrac{ \sin x - \cos x + 1 } { -2\sin x  \cos x} dx$$

we get

$$I=-\frac{1}2\int \sec x~ dx+\frac{1}2\int \csc x~ dx-\int \csc (2x)~ dx$$

So we convert it into the sum of three basic integrals. Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Very clever technique +1.

Comment: thank you.. :-)

Comment: @MathFail I can take it from there.

Comment: great, glad it helps @Bob

Answer (score 4):

Here is a compact solution via the substitution $t=x-\frac\pi4$
\begin{align}
& \int \frac{ 1 } { \sin x - \cos x - 1} dx\\
 =& \int \frac{ 1 } { \sqrt2 \sin t - 1} dt
= \int \frac{ \sec^2 t \ (\sqrt2 \sin t - 1)} { \sec^2 t\ (\sqrt2 \sin t - 1)^2} dt\\
=& \int \frac{d (\sqrt2 \sec t - \tan t)} {  (\sqrt2 \sec t - \tan t)^2-1}=-\coth^{-1}(\sqrt2 \sec t - \tan t)+C
\end{align}

Comment: Wonderful and elegant solution!

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on your second approach, substitute $v=\sqrt u$ :

$$\begin{align*}
&\int \dfrac{ du } { u^2 + u^{\frac{3}{2}} - u^{ \frac{1}{2}} - 1 } \\
&= \int \frac{2v\,dv}{v^4 + v^3 - v - 1} \\
&= \int \frac{2v\,dv}{(v-1)(v+1)(v^2+v+1)} \\
&= \frac13 \int \left(\frac3{v+1} + \frac1{v-1}-\frac{2(2v+1)}{v^2+v+1}\right) \, dv
\end{align*}$$

---

Alternatively, substitute $u=\tan x$ :

$$\begin{align*}
& \int \frac{dx}{\sin x - \cos x - 1} \\
&= \int \frac{\sec^2x\,dx}{\sec x(\tan x - 1 - \sec x)} \\
&= \int \frac{du}{\sqrt{u^2+1}(u - 1 - \sqrt{u^2+1})} \\
&= \frac12 \int \left(\frac1{u\sqrt{1+u^2}} - \frac1{\sqrt{1+u^2}} - \frac1u\right) \, du \\
&= -\frac12 \tanh^{-1}\left(\sqrt{1+u^2}\right)  - \frac12 \sinh^{-1}u - \frac12\ln|u| + C \\
&= -\frac12 \tanh^{-1}\left|\sec x\right| - \frac12 \sinh^{-1}(\tan x) - \frac12\ln\left|\tan x\right| + C
\end{align*}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
\int_{ }^{ }\frac{1}{\sin\left(x\right)-\cos\left(x\right)-1}dx &= \int_{ }^{ }\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{\sin^{2}\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x\right)\cos\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x\right)}dx \\
&= \int_{ }^{ }\frac{\sin\left(x\right)}{\left(1+\cos\left(x\right)\right)\left(1-\cos\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x\right)\right)}dx \\
&= \int_{ }^{ }\frac{\left(\frac{2}{1+\cos\left(x\right)}\right)\sin\left(x\right)}{2\left(1-\cos\left(x\right)-\sin\left(x\right)\right)}dx \\
&= \int_{ }^{ }\frac{\sec^{2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\sin\left(x\right)}{2-2\cos\left(x\right)-2\sin\left(x\right)}dx \\
&= \int_{ }^{ }\frac{\sec^{2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{2\left(\frac{1-\cos\left(x\right)}{\sin\left(x\right)}-1\right)}dx \\
&= \int_{ }^{ }\frac{\sec^{2}\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)}{2\left(\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-1\right)}dx \\
&= \int_{ }^{ }\frac{1}{\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-1}d\left(\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-1\right) \\
&= \ln\left|\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)-1\right|+C
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{aligned}
I & =\int \frac{1}{\sin x-(\cos x+1)} d x \\
& =\int \frac{1}{2 \sin \frac{x}{2} \cos \frac{x}{2}-2 \cos ^2 \frac{x}{2}} d x \\
& =\int \frac{\sec ^2 t}{\tan t-1} d t, \quad \textrm{ where }t=\frac x2 \\
& =\ln |\tan t-1|+C\\
& =\ln \left|\tan \frac{x}{2}-1\right|+C
\end{aligned}
$$